# Docker Compose Expose Spark Worker UI Ports Dynamically to Host When Scaling

Tags: apache-spark, docker, dockerfile

I have Apache Spark running inside a container created via Docker Compose. When I create the worker, I specify which port on the host machine (my laptop) is mapped to the web UI port `8081` on the worker. With 1 container, this works fine because I can bind `8081:8081` and the containerized Spark Master Web UI correctly links to `localhost:8081`.

The issue is that when I scale the number of workers via `docker-compose scale worker=3`, I cannot specify a port on the host machine in my `docker-compose.yml` because scaling will conflict.

I have tried using dynamic port mapping, but this results in host port that is forwarded to the worker port 8081 will be something like 32XXX but the Spark Master WebUI links will still assume the worker WebUI is on port 8081 meaning none of the links work.

Is there a way to scale my containers without having port clashes

The relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
worker:
  image: gettyimages/spark
  command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker 
  spark://master:7077
  hostname: worker
  environment:
    SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
    SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
    SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8881
    SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8081
    SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
  links:
    - master
    - cassandra
    - kafka
  expose:
    - 7012
    - 7013
    - 7014
    - 7015
    - 7016
    - 8881
  ports:
    - 8081 # dynamic port binding. ends up being 32XXX:8081
  # - 8081:8081 only works with 1 container
```

Is there something that could be done with the `SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS` or dynamic variable substitution in the compose file?